# How to Automatically add current user's Timezone in ISO 8601 Date Time

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need a user input for date and time from a user and then generate the final date and time isn ISO 8601 format for posting to Facebook API.

I have done the most part but for now, I have to manually add the time zone string manually by concatenation.

Is there a way to add the current time zone automatically in the finally generated date time.

```
from datetime import datetime

user_date = input("Enter the schedule date/time(YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS): ")

print("Schedule in the ISO format is: ", datetime.strptime(user_date,"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S").isoformat())
```

**Current Output**: 2023-12-03T15:30:00

**Expected Output**: 2023-12-03T15:30:00+05:30

I can do like this this..

```
print("Date in the ISO format is: ", datetime.strptime(user_date,"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S").isoformat()+"+05:30")
```

but I want to add the time zone automatically. For example, mine is Asia/Kolkata so it should add "+05:30" but for other time zones, it would be different.

Comment: `datetime.strptime(user_date, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S").astimezone().isoformat()`